# Hessian of Gaussian eigenvalues for 3D image with Python

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy-ndarray, eigenvalue, hessian-matrix

I have a 3D image and I want to calculate the Hessian of Gaussian eigenvalues for this image. I would like to have the three eigenvalues of the Hessian approximation for each voxel. This feature seems to be something very common in image processing.

Is there  an existing implementation of this feature (like scipy.ndimage.laplace for laplacian calculation)? And is there one that parallels calculations?

I tried to do it manually, through numpy operations but its not optimal because:

1. I have to compute the Hessian on all the Voxels which tack time and lot of RAM
2. Output data seems extremely noisy (it may be because of data type conversion during operations)
3. the sum of eigenvalues is not equal to the laplacian.

Ideally I'm just looking for an existing implementation, I put this code as an example of the last statement.

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as sn
import h5py
import time

def hessian_eigenvalues(x,Mask):
    
    H=hessian(x)
    t2=time.time()
    
    print("   Calculate feature:  Hessian eigenvalues")
    eigen=np.linalg.eigvals(H[Mask])
    print("   Feature calculated  ---time: ",time.time()-t2)
    del H
    return eigen

def hessian(x):
    t2=time.time()
    print("   Calculate feature:  Hessian ")
    x_grad = np.gradient(x) 
    hessian = np.empty(x.shape + (x.ndim, x.ndim)  , dtype=x.dtype) 
    for k, grad_k in enumerate(x_grad):
        # iterate over dimensions
        # apply gradient again to every component of the first derivative.
        tmp_grad = np.gradient(grad_k) 
        for l, grad_kl in enumerate(tmp_grad):
            hessian[ :, :,:,k, l] = grad_kl
    print("   Feature calculated  ---time: ",time.time()-t2)
    return hessian

t2=time.time()
print("   Loading special feature:  raw datas ")


raw=h5py.File(r"Datas\9003\Variables\raw.h5", 'r')
Base_data=np.asarray(raw['exported_data'][:,:,:],dtype=np.uint16)
raw.close
print("   Feature loaded  ---time: ",time.time()-t2)

t2=time.time()

print("   Loading special feature:  masque")
m = h5py.File(r"Datas\9003\Masques\9003_masque.h5", 'r')
Mask=np.nonzero(m["exported_data"][:,:,:])
m.close
print("   Feature loaded  ---time: ",time.time()-t2)

eig = hessian_eigenvalues(Base_data,Mask)
```

Comment: You say that you "don't want to calculate the Hessian of Gaussian eigenvalues", but that you would like "to have the tree [three?] eigenvalues of the Hessian approximation for each voxel". This is a bit confusing. I'm presuming that the "don't" is a typo?

Comment: Next, please make your question explicit. Are you looking for debugging help? Are you looking for an existing implementation? (this is out of scope for SO though.) Are you looking for help speeding up the code? If you are looking for debugging help, I suggest that you explain what "does not work very well" means, include actual output and expected output.

Comment: Actually I want to calculate the Hessian of Gaussian eigenvalues, I don't know why I wrote a "don't" here, sorry. Anyway  now that's corected.

Comment: I'm looking for an existing implementation if there is one. The code here is as an example of what I'm doing instead

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow" ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)).

Comment: But [DIPlib has a Hessian of Gaussian](https://diplib.github.io/diplib-docs/group__linear.html#ga00a6ecb0c0a5b1d7eb8403b4e6434a9b) function and can [compute eigenvalues](https://diplib.github.io/diplib-docs/group__math__tensor.html#ga4fa9cdf7cec61868a8ee1c027d15000a). For the Python bindings to DIPlib [see here](https://pypi.org/project/diplib/).

Comment: By the way, the noisiness is because you don't apply a Gaussian filter. You should smooth your image first, or even better use Gaussian derivative filters like we do in DIPlib.

Comment: Am I missing something? It looks like you want the eigenvalues of the hessian, not the hessian of the eigenvalues? If you just want the eigenvalues themselves you can drop the jacobian-vector-product directly into an iterative eigensolver rather than instantiating the Hessian (if RAM is the problem you're facing?).